# Windows 8 Store Instant Messaging App

Tags: c#, wcf, websocket, windows-store-apps, instant-messaging

I know php and my friend  knows c#.

We have to develop a windows 8 metro app that have the capability of instant messaging.

What else do we need to know?
WCF is out of the list because of its limitations towards metro app. So I need to know options other than wcf that should be approached to?

Do MQTT, XMPP or WEBSOCKETS have to do something with our project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMPP sounds like the best option since it's a communications and chat protocol. The others could possibly also be used, but then you'd have to reinvent most of what is already in XMPP.

There are [multiple servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software#Comparison_by_XEP_implementation_status) already available, all of which cover at least basic chat.

On the Windows Store client side it's a bit harder, but [the MatrixXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) *should* work well. I've not used in personally though, so you'll have to do your own research that it covers all that you need.